# Applying for UK visitor visa outside home country?

Tags: visas, uk

I have family that are Indian citizens but currently overseas on holiday. Can they visit the local visa application centre to submit biometrics etc?
The ECB05 rule suggests they can https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/where-to-apply-ecb05/ecb5-where-to-apply-the-policy

A solicitor advised me that they need to be resident in the country, however there's nothing in the rule that specifies this.
It simply says "*You should be present legally in the country or territory you’re applying from*."

Has anyone had experience of this?

Ideally I would like to make the application for them here in the UK and they they visit a local visa center whilst on holiday.

I'd really appreciate if anyone can enlighten me here.

From other boards I can see people have queried this directly with UKVI but no answers.

Comment: Not sure why this has been closed. The thread referred does have the answer. I just need to know whether they can be a tourist abroad and apply for uk visitor visa, or do they have to be a resident in thay country? The rule o ly say have to be in the country legally.

Comment: The thread referenced does or does not have the answer? If it does *not* have a suitable answer, add more specifics that make it clear how your question is different and try again.